# How to fix llvm building using cmake

Tags: llvm

I wanted to follow this simple [llvm tutorial](https://llvm.org/docs/CMake.html).

I git cloned "llvm-project" and did not change anything! Then in "llvm" folder I created a folder "build", changed directory to it, and called:

```
$ cmake ../
```

Unfortunatetly, I got the following error:

```
 -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

The full message is as follows:

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 11.4.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 11.4.0
-- The ASM compiler identification is GNU
-- Found assembler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:97 (message):
                                                                             
                                                                             
  No build type selected.  You need to pass -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=<type> in     
  order to configure LLVM.                                                   
                                                                             
  Available options are:                                                     
                                                                             
    * -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release - For an optimized build with no assertions or debug info.                                                               
    * -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug - For an unoptimized build with assertions and debug info.                                                                 
    * -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo - For an optimized build with no assertions but with debug info.                                                  
    * -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=MinSizeRel - For a build optimized for size instead of speed.                                                                    
                                                                             
  Learn more about these options in our documentation at                     
  https://llvm.org/docs/CMake.html#cmake-build-type
```

The output of CMakeOutput.log is:

```
The system is: Linux - 6.5.0-18-generic - x86_64
Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" succeeded.
Compiler: /usr/bin/cc 
Build flags: 
Id flags:  

The output was:
0


Compilation of the C compiler identification source "CMakeCCompilerId.c" produced "a.out"

The C compiler identification is GNU, found in "/home/kamil/Documents/llvm/llvm-project/llvm/build/CMakeFiles/3.22.1/CompilerIdC/a.out"

Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" succeeded.
Compiler: /usr/bin/c++ 
Build flags: 
Id flags:  

The output was:
0


Compilation of the CXX compiler identification source "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" produced "a.out"

The CXX compiler identification is GNU, found in "/home/kamil/Documents/llvm/llvm-project/llvm/build/CMakeFiles/3.22.1/CompilerIdCXX/a.out"

Checking whether the ASM compiler is GNU using "--version" matched "(GNU assembler)|(GCC)|(Free Software Foundation)":
cc (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Detecting C compiler ABI info compiled with the following output:
Change Dir: /home/kamil/Documents/llvm/llvm-project/llvm/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/gmake -f Makefile cmTC_5026a/fast && /usr/bin/gmake  -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_5026a.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_5026a.dir/build
gmake[1]: Entering directory '/home/kamil/Documents/llvm/llvm-project/llvm/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_5026a.dir/CMakeCCompilerABI.c.o
/usr/bin/cc   -v -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_5026a.dir/CMakeCCompilerABI.c.o -c /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/CMakeCCompilerABI.c
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=/usr/bin/cc
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none:amdgcn-amdhsa
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-11/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,brig,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++,m2 --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-11 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --enable-bootstrap --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --enable-libphobos-checking=release --with-target-system-zlib=auto --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --enable-cet --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none=/build/gcc-11-XeT9lY/gcc-11-11.4.0/debian/tmp-nvptx/usr,amdgcn-amdhsa=/build/gcc-11-XeT9lY/gcc-11-11.4.0/debian/tmp-gcn/usr --without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu --with-build-config=bootstrap-lto-lean --enable-link-serialization=2
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib zstd
gcc version 11.4.0 (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-o' 'CMakeFiles/cmTC_5026a.dir/CMakeCCompilerABI.c.o' '-c' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64' '-dumpdir' 'CMakeFiles/cmTC_5026a.dir/'
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/cc1 -quiet -v -imultiarch x86_64-linux-gnu /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/CMakeCCompilerABI.c -quiet -dumpdir CMakeFiles/cmTC_5026a.dir/ -dumpbase CMakeCCompilerABI.c.c -dumpbase-ext .c -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -version -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Wformat-security -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -o /tmp/cct53KJE.s
GNU C17 (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) version 11.4.0 (x86_64-linux-gnu)
    compiled by GNU C version 11.4.0, GMP version 6.2.1, MPFR version 4.1.0, MPC version 1.2.1, isl version isl-0.24-GMP

GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/include/x86_64-linux-gnu"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/include-fixed"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
End of search list.
GNU C17 (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) version 11.4.0 (x86_64-linux-gnu)
    compiled by GNU C version 11.4.0, GMP version 6.2.1, MPFR version 4.1.0, MPC version 1.2.1, isl version isl-0.24-GMP

GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
Compiler executable checksum: 50eaa2331df977b8016186198deb2d18
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-o' 'CMakeFiles/cmTC_5026a.dir/CMakeCCompilerABI.c.o' '-c' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64' '-dumpdir' 'CMakeFiles/cmTC_5026a.dir/'
 as -v --64 -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_5026a.dir/CMakeCCompilerABI.c.o /tmp/cct53KJE.s
GNU assembler version 2.38 (x86_64-linux-gnu) using BFD version (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.38
COMPILER_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/
LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../lib/:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../:/lib/:/usr/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-o' 'CMakeFiles/cmTC_5026a.dir/CMakeCCompilerABI.c.o' '-c' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64' '-dumpdir' 'CMakeFiles/cmTC_5026a.dir/CMakeCCompilerABI.c.'
Linking C executable cmTC_5026a
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_5026a.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/cc  -v CMakeFiles/cmTC_5026a.dir/CMakeCCompilerABI.c.o -o cmTC_5026a 
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=/usr/bin/cc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/lto-wrapper
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none:amdgcn-amdhsa
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-11/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,brig,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++,m2 --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-11 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --enable-bootstrap --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --enable-libphobos-checking=release --with-target-system-zlib=auto --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --enable-cet --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none=/build/gcc-11-XeT9lY/gcc-11-11.4.0/debian/tmp-nvptx/usr,amdgcn-amdhsa=/build/gcc-11-XeT9lY/gcc-11-11.4.0/debian/tmp-gcn/usr --without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu --with-build-config=bootstrap-lto-lean --enable-link-serialization=2
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib zstd
gcc version 11.4.0 (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 
COMPILER_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/
LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../lib/:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../:/lib/:/usr/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-o' 'cmTC_5026a' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64' '-dumpdir' 'cmTC_5026a.'
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/collect2 -plugin /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/liblto_plugin.so -plugin-opt=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/lto-wrapper -plugin-opt=-fresolution=/tmp/cciLlmLe.res -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s --build-id --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 --hash-style=gnu --as-needed -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -pie -z now -z relro -o cmTC_5026a /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/crtbeginS.o -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../lib -L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../.. CMakeFiles/cmTC_5026a.dir/CMakeCCompilerABI.c.o -lgcc --push-state --as-needed -lgcc_s --pop-state -lc -lgcc --push-state --as-needed -lgcc_s --pop-state /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/crtendS.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-o' 'cmTC_5026a' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64' '-dumpdir' 'cmTC_5026a.'
gmake[1]: Leaving directory '/home/kamil/Documents/llvm/llvm-project/llvm/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'



Parsed C implicit include dir info from above output: rv=done
  found start of include info
  found start of implicit include info
    add: [/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/include]
    add: [/usr/local/include]
    add: [/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu]
    add: [/usr/include]
  end of search list found
  collapse include dir [/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/include] ==> [/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/include]
  collapse include dir [/usr/local/include] ==> [/usr/local/include]
  collapse include dir [/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu] ==> [/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu]
  collapse include dir [/usr/include] ==> [/usr/include]
  implicit include dirs: [/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/include;/usr/local/include;/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu;/usr/include]


Parsed C implicit link information from above output:
  link line regex: [^( *|.*[/\])(ld|CMAKE_LINK_STARTFILE-NOTFOUND|([^/\]+-)?ld|collect2)[^/\]*( |$)]
  ignore line: [Change Dir: /home/kamil/Documents/llvm/llvm-project/llvm/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp]
  ignore line: []
  ignore line: [Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/gmake -f Makefile cmTC_5026a/fast && /usr/bin/gmake  -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_5026a.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_5026a.dir/build]
  ignore line: [gmake[1]: Entering directory '/home/kamil/Documents/llvm/llvm-project/llvm/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp']
  ignore line: [Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_5026a.dir/CMakeCCompilerABI.c.o]
  ignore line: [/usr/bin/cc   -v -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_5026a.dir/CMakeCCompilerABI.c.o -c /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/CMakeCCompilerABI.c]
  ignore line: [Using built-in specs.]
  ignore line: [COLLECT_GCC=/usr/bin/cc]
  ignore line: [OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none:amdgcn-amdhsa]
  ignore line: [OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1]
  ignore line: [Target: x86_64-linux-gnu]
  ignore line: [Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-11/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c ada c++ go brig d fortran objc obj-c++ m2 --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-11 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --enable-bootstrap --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --enable-libphobos-checking=release --with-target-system-zlib=auto --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --enable-cet --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32 m64 mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none=/build/gcc-11-XeT9lY/gcc-11-11.4.0/debian/tmp-nvptx/usr amdgcn-amdhsa=/build/gcc-11-XeT9lY/gcc-11-11.4.0/debian/tmp-gcn/usr --without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu --with-build-config=bootstrap-lto-lean --enable-link-serialization=2]
  ignore line: [Thread model: posix]
  ignore line: [Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib zstd]
  ignore line: [gcc version 11.4.0 (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) ]
  ignore line: [COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-o' 'CMakeFiles/cmTC_5026a.dir/CMakeCCompilerABI.c.o' '-c' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64' '-dumpdir' 'CMakeFiles/cmTC_5026a.dir/']
  ignore line: [ /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/cc1 -quiet -v -imultiarch x86_64-linux-gnu /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/CMakeCCompilerABI.c -quiet -dumpdir CMakeFiles/cmTC_5026a.dir/ -dumpbase CMakeCCompilerABI.c.c -dumpbase-ext .c -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -version -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Wformat-security -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -o /tmp/cct53KJE.s]
  ignore line: [GNU C17 (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) version 11.4.0 (x86_64-linux-gnu)]
  ignore line: [    compiled by GNU C version 11.4.0  GMP version 6.2.1  MPFR version 4.1.0  MPC version 1.2.1  isl version isl-0.24-GMP]
  ignore line: []
  ignore line: [GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072]
  ignore line: [ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/include/x86_64-linux-gnu"]
  ignore line: [ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/include-fixed"]
  ignore line: [ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/include"]
  ignore line: [#include "..." search starts here:]
  ignore line: [#include <...> search starts here:]
  ignore line: [ /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/include]
  ignore line: [ /usr/local/include]
  ignore line: [ /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu]
  ignore line: [ /usr/include]
  ignore line: [End of search list.]
  ignore line: [GNU C17 (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) version 11.4.0 (x86_64-linux-gnu)]
  ignore line: [    compiled by GNU C version 11.4.0  GMP version 6.2.1  MPFR version 4.1.0  MPC version 1.2.1  isl version isl-0.24-GMP]
  ignore line: []
  ignore line: [GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072]
  ignore line: [Compiler executable checksum: 50eaa2331df977b8016186198deb2d18]
  ignore line: [COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-o' 'CMakeFiles/cmTC_5026a.dir/CMakeCCompilerABI.c.o' '-c' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64' '-dumpdir' 'CMakeFiles/cmTC_5026a.dir/']
  ignore line: [ as -v --64 -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_5026a.dir/CMakeCCompilerABI.c.o /tmp/cct53KJE.s]
  ignore line: [GNU assembler version 2.38 (x86_64-linux-gnu) using BFD version (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.38]
  ignore line: [COMPILER_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/]
  ignore line: [LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../lib/:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../:/lib/:/usr/lib/]
  ignore line: [COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-o' 'CMakeFiles/cmTC_5026a.dir/CMakeCCompilerABI.c.o' '-c' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64' '-dumpdir' 'CMakeFiles/cmTC_5026a.dir/CMakeCCompilerABI.c.']
  ignore line: [Linking C executable cmTC_5026a]
  ignore line: [/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_5026a.dir/link.txt --verbose=1]
  ignore line: [/usr/bin/cc  -v CMakeFiles/cmTC_5026a.dir/CMakeCCompilerABI.c.o -o cmTC_5026a ]
  ignore line: [Using built-in specs.]
  ignore line: [COLLECT_GCC=/usr/bin/cc]
  ignore line: [COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/lto-wrapper]
  ignore line: [OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none:amdgcn-amdhsa]
  ignore line: [OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1]
  ignore line: [Target: x86_64-linux-gnu]
  ignore line: [Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-11/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c ada c++ go brig d fortran objc obj-c++ m2 --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-11 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --enable-bootstrap --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --enable-libphobos-checking=release --with-target-system-zlib=auto --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --enable-cet --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32 m64 mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none=/build/gcc-11-XeT9lY/gcc-11-11.4.0/debian/tmp-nvptx/usr amdgcn-amdhsa=/build/gcc-11-XeT9lY/gcc-11-11.4.0/debian/tmp-gcn/usr --without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu --with-build-config=bootstrap-lto-lean --enable-link-serialization=2]
  ignore line: [Thread model: posix]
  ignore line: [Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib zstd]
  ignore line: [gcc version 11.4.0 (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) ]
  ignore line: [COMPILER_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/]
  ignore line: [LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../lib/:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../:/lib/:/usr/lib/]
  ignore line: [COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-o' 'cmTC_5026a' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64' '-dumpdir' 'cmTC_5026a.']
  link line: [ /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/collect2 -plugin /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/liblto_plugin.so -plugin-opt=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/lto-wrapper -plugin-opt=-fresolution=/tmp/cciLlmLe.res -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s --build-id --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 --hash-style=gnu --as-needed -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -pie -z now -z relro -o cmTC_5026a /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/crtbeginS.o -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../lib -L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../.. CMakeFiles/cmTC_5026a.dir/CMakeCCompilerABI.c.o -lgcc --push-state --as-needed -lgcc_s --pop-state -lc -lgcc --push-state --as-needed -lgcc_s --pop-state /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/crtendS.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o]
    arg [/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/collect2] ==> ignore
    arg [-plugin] ==> ignore
    arg [/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/liblto_plugin.so] ==> ignore
    arg [-plugin-opt=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/lto-wrapper] ==> ignore
    arg [-plugin-opt=-fresolution=/tmp/cciLlmLe.res] ==> ignore
    arg [-plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc] ==> ignore
    arg [-plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s] ==> ignore
    arg [-plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lc] ==> ignore
    arg [-plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc] ==> ignore
    arg [-plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s] ==> ignore
    arg [--build-id] ==> ignore
    arg [--eh-frame-hdr] ==> ignore
    arg [-m] ==> ignore
    arg [elf_x86_64] ==> ignore
    arg [--hash-style=gnu] ==> ignore
    arg [--as-needed] ==> ignore
    arg [-dynamic-linker] ==> ignore
    arg [/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2] ==> ignore
    arg [-pie] ==> ignore
    arg [-znow] ==> ignore
    arg [-zrelro] ==> ignore
    arg [-o] ==> ignore
    arg [cmTC_5026a] ==> ignore
    arg [/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o] ==> obj [/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o]
    arg [/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o] ==> obj [/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o]
    arg [/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/crtbeginS.o] ==> obj [/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/crtbeginS.o]
    arg [-L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11] ==> dir [/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11]
    arg [-L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu] ==> dir [/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu]
    arg [-L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../lib] ==> dir [/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../lib]
    arg [-L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu] ==> dir [/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu]
    arg [-L/lib/../lib] ==> dir [/lib/../lib]
    arg [-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu] ==> dir [/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu]
    arg [-L/usr/lib/../lib] ==> dir [/usr/lib/../lib]
    arg [-L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../..] ==> dir [/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../..]
... the rest was redacted due to the limitation of the number of characters
```

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide value for `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` (e.g. `Debug`, `Release`, etc.):

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug ..
```